# adb shell pm: command grant not found

Tags: android, shell, adb

On this site [AutoTools Secure Settings](https://joaoapps.com/AutoApps/Help/Info/com.joaomgcd.autotools/com.joaomgcd.autotools.activity.ActivityConfigsettings.html), I was advised to use the following command:

```
adb shell pm grant com.joaomgcd.autotools android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

However, the command `grant` is not available. Does that maybe have to do with my Android version which is `4.0.3`?

```
orschiro@x230 ~ $ adb shell pm grant com.joaomgcd.autotools android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
Error: unknown command 'grant'
usage: pm list packages [-f] [-d] [-e] [-s] [-e] [-u] [FILTER]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to change the command

```
adb -d shell pm grant com.joaomgcd.autotools android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS
```

I think the parameter **-d** to invoke grant permission over **ADB**

Comment: is it possible for the write settings?    WRITE_SETTINGS

Comment: Yes. You can grant  all permissions by this method.

Comment: thank you for your reply i my case could not do this kindly help me i am doing the same with my package name and i have a rooted device

Comment: Yes i entered there

Comment: C:\Users\Teespire>adb shell
p281:/ $ pm grant <packageName> android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS
Operation not allowed: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS is not a changeable permission type

Comment: "Settings -> Apps -> Configure Apps (the gear button) ->Modify system settings."  And Grant permssion for ur app here. redirect from ur application to this screen if u want a shortcut

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182933/discussion-between-innocent-and-tomin-b-azhakathu).